# HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed

Tags: internet-explorer-8

i made a website , and it seems to work in every brwoser except IE8, which some of the users still use to visit the site. 
With the current code, IE8 gives me the following error:

Message: HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917)

As a test, i removed the whole script block with the $(document).ready(function(), but that does not seem to be the problem. IE8 still gives the error and does not load the whole website, only 75% of the page is loaded, so users won't be able to see the contact form.

Can anyone tell me what part of the code i should change?
I pasted the whole code here: http://pastebin.com/Nr1C49M0

Comment: seems that you're missing a closing tag (for example `</div>`) in your markup.

Comment: any idea which line? i can't find it with pspad?